# How can you deploy a bitbucket-plugin (already built as jar) to the server via terminal?

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

We run a Bitbucket Server on version 7.21 and have recently developed a Plugin for it. Since this plugin finally reached a stable Version we wanted to integrate it into our cd/ci pipeline (bamboo).

We can build the plugin via bamboo build plan alright, but we are facing an issue when trying to deploy it.

atlas-sdk's "atlas-install-plugin" does not work for us (afaik) because we are not in the project space, but only have the built jar itself.

Is there any way to copy the jar to a specific location on the bitbucket server and it auto-deploys or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone searching, I found the solution.
You can install plugins via the rest api: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/installing-uninstalling-upgrading-and-downgrading-marketplace-apps-on-confluence-using-rest-api-1005343959.html